# How to set MTU on bridge device with netplan & networkd?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, systemd, mtu

I want to use netplan with the networkd backend to bring up an ethernet bridge, with a specific MTU.

I can configure the MTU parameter in the netplan files, for both the bridge device and ethernet interfaces, and I see this propagated into the systemd networkd configurations -- however the actual devices are only brought up with the default 1500 MTU.

This is the netplan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      mtu: 9000
  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses:
        - 10.1.1.1/24
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces:
        - eno1
      mtu: 9000
```

That generates networkd configurations that include `MTUBytes=9000` for both the bridge and ethernet links.

Any thoughts?

My current hacky workaround is to put a script in `/usr/lib/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/` which calls `ip link set mtu ...` but surely there is a better way?

Versions involved:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- netplan 1.10.1-5build1
- networkd-dispatcher 1.7-0ubuntu3.3
- systemd 237-3ubuntu10.9